# Is the resolution of MYD13A2/MOD13A2 ( MODIS 16 day 1km Global Vegetation Indices) erroneous in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, ndvi, vegetation-index

The MODIS vegetation indices collection shows a resolution of 111319.4 metres in Google Earth Engine when, in fact, it should be 1000 metres.

Below is my code:

```js
var Veg = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13A2").filterDate ('2009-04-15', 
'2009-04-30').max().select('NDVI');
print('Scale in meters:', Veg.projection().nominalScale());
```

I checked the resolution because I wanted to change resolution of my 90m Digital Elevation Model to 1000m using MYD13A2 data, but it gave the following error:

```js
Layer 1: Tile error: Too many input pixels per output pixel. Need 1440001, but only 10000 allowed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [nominal scale](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeprojectionnominalscale) of the a [MOD13A2](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MOD13A2) image is indeed around 1000m:

```js
var sampleImage = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13A2").first())
                    .select('NDVI');

print('Scale in meters:', sampleImage.projection().nominalScale());
```

However, your code example is not printing out the scale of an MOD13A2 image, but rather is printing out the scale of a composited image (which happens to be derived from MOD13A2 images). Your script calls [ee.ImageCollection.max()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollectionmax), which reduces all images in an ee.ImageCollection to a single ee.Image object. Because the images in the collection may (and often do) have different projections, a default projection of WGS84 with a 1-degree scale ([EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/)) is applied to the result. 1 degree at the equator is approximately 111 kilometers, which matches the result you received.

For more information, see the [Projections](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections) section of the Earth Engine documentation.